# Is there a way to append to current item in a text file rather than writing to a newline in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have some XSLT which is generating wiki markup:

```
||Host / SIM||||User CPU - Avg||User CPU - 95th% tile||System CPU - Avg||System CPU - 95th% tile||
                               |dub-001544-vm01
                                            |23.88
                                            |60.87
                                            |9.83
                                            |13.8
```

The above markup generates a table, but it should be formatted like this:

```
||Host / SIM||||User CPU - Avg||User CPU - 95th% tile||System CPU - Avg||System CPU - 95th% tile||
|dub-001544-vm01 |23.88 |60.87 |9.83 |13.8
```

All cell entries should be on the same line. The XSLT to generate the first cell item (dub-001544-vm01) is:

```
<xsl:template name="populateHostSim">
    <xsl:param name="action" />
    <xsl:param name="mode" />
    <xsl:param name="currentHost" />
    <xsl:param name="currentResult" />
    <xsl:message>In populateHostSim, with mode: <xsl:value-of select="$mode"/></xsl:message>
    <xsl:message>In populateHostSim, with current host: <xsl:value-of select="$currentHost"/></xsl:message>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]">
            <xsl:if test="$action='header'">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="$mode='html'">
                <th>
                    <b>Host / SIM</b>
                </th>
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>||Host / SIM||</xsl:text>
             </xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$currentHost">
            <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$mode='html'">
                <td>
                    <xsl:call-template name="populateSimId">
                        <xsl:with-param name="currentSimResult" select="$currentResult" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="currentSimHost" select="$currentHost" />
                    </xsl:call-template>

                    <b>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$currentHost" />
                    </b>
                </td>
            </xsl:when> 
            <xsl:otherwise>
               TD: |<xsl:value-of select="$currentHost" />                 
            </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Then the actual figures (|23.88 |60.87 |9.83 |13.8) are done with a different template:

```
<xsl:template name="cpu">
    <xsl:param name="action" />
    <xsl:param name="mode" />
    <xsl:param name="currentHost" />
    <xsl:param name="currentResult" />
    <xsl:if test="$action='header'">
        <xsl:call-template name="populateCpuHeader">
            <xsl:with-param name="mode" select="$mode" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]/server">
            <xsl:variable name="PATH"
                select="/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]/server[hostname eq $currentHost]/hardwareStats" />
            <xsl:for-each
                select="distinct-values(/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]/server[child::hardwareStats]/hardwareStats/cpuStats/@type)">
                <xsl:variable name="type" select="." />
                <xsl:variable name="avg"
                    select="$PATH/cpuStats[@type eq $type]/avg/text()" />
                <xsl:variable name="percentile"
                    select="$PATH/cpuStats[@type eq $type]/percentile/text()" />

                <xsl:if test="$action='data'">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$mode='html'">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$avg" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$percentile" />
                    </td>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                    | <xsl:value-of select="$avg" />
                    | <xsl:value-of select="$percentile" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:if test="$action='data'">
                <xsl:call-template name="fillCpuTableCellWithEmptyTag" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

At the moment I am inserting 'TD:' in front of the cell entry , so that I can pick it up later in Java, and reformat it, before pushing it to Confluence:

```
 List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("summary.markup"), Charset.defaultCharset());
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder rowBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Line item: " + lines.get(i));
            if(lines.get(i).trim().startsWith("TD:")) {
                String item = Arrays.asList(lines.get(i).split(":")).get(1).trim();
                System.out.println("Item:" + item); 
                rowBuilder.append(item);
            } else {
                b.append(String.format("%s%s", lines.get(i), "\r\n"));
            }
        }  
        rowBuilder.append("|");
        b.append(String.format("%s%s",rowBuilder, "\r\n"));
        page.setContent(b.toString());
```

That is going to get messy as the table becomes more complex. It would be better if I could do it in XSLT.

Ideas greatly appreciated as always :)

Comment: In one place you have used `xsl:text` to control the text output, so I would think that changing `<xsl:otherwise>
               TD: |<xsl:value-of select="$currentHost" />                 
            </xsl:otherwise>` to `<xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>TD: |</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$currentHost"/></xsl:otherwise>` allows you to control the text output at that point as well.

Comment: Hi Martin, I omitted a call to another template in the question - have added it now, but your answer actually helped me fix the problem, I just had to wrap the call in the cpu template with <xsl:text>, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write XSLT code with

```
        <xsl:otherwise>
           TD: |<xsl:value-of select="$currentHost" />                 
        </xsl:otherwise>
```

or

```
                <xsl:otherwise>
                | <xsl:value-of select="$avg" />
                | <xsl:value-of select="$percentile" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
```

then the whitespace and the line breaks in e.g. 
                    `|` will be output. You can control the text better by using `xsl:text` explicitly, as in

```
<xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:text>TD: |</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="$currentHost"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

As an alternative, as you use XSLT 2.0 where `value-of` allows outputting a sequence, you could try e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="'|', $avg, '|', $percentile"/>`.

Finally, in both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 you can use `concat`, e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="concat('TD: |', $currentHost)"/>`.